# Passing on MongoDB data to D3 viz using an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, d3.js, mongoose

This is probably super simple, but for a contrived example:

I need to pass on a single value, say I get in Angular:

```
Time remaining is: {{ hoursLeft }}
<donut-chart data=hoursLeft> </donut-chart>
```

Where donutChart is an Angular directive that uses D3 to process data. If I instead of `data=hoursLeft` put say `23` the thing seems to work, but if I put `hoursLeft`, I get `null` when I try to log the value of `hoursLeft` in the D3 script. However, when I print to HTML (as above), I get the value, no problem.

**EDIT**: I did some more investigating and **the problem seemed to be not in the value passing** , **but in the fact that the MongoDB query was not ready** with the data by the time I was calling the directive.

I know that a query must be deferred using promise, but I can normally print the values to the web page. How do I make is so that the function call to the directive itself is deferred?

I currently tried using `$watch`, but I get an error when I include this in my directive:

```
directive(
    'donutChart', 
        function() {
        // lots of D3 stuff
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { data: '=' }
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                  if (newValue)
                      console.log("I see a data change!");
              }, true);
          }
      }
    });
```

When instead of the `function` I include just `link: link`, the visualization seems to run fine, but I get `null`, which is processed as a number, but obviously is not what I wanted.

**So ultimately I need to either deferred the directive or make it `$watch` for changes, neither of which I managed to do.**

```
The error (with the set up above) I get now is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier directives.js:98
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module test due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module zurich.directives due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'test.directives' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: Kind of hard to tell without seeing the directive code. Consider making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something like that.

Comment: this works -http://jsfiddle.net/en6k0zsc/1/ didn't really change anything apart from getting the fiddle to not throw errors.